# How To validate Radio Bottom With Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

My code HTML

```
<input type="radio" class="w3-radio" name="ket_jawaban[<?php echo $no2;?>]" value="<?php echo $row->pil1;?>"  oninput="this.className = ''"> <?php echo $row->pil2;?>
<input type="radio" class="w3-radio" name="ket_jawaban[<?php echo $no2;?>]" value="<?php echo $row->pil2;?>" oninput="this.className = ''"> <?php echo $row->pil2;?>
<input type="radio" class="w3-radio" name="ket_jawaban[<?php echo $no2;?>]" value="<?php echo $row->pil3;?>" oninput="this.className = ''"><?php echo $row->pil3;?>
<input type="radio" class="w3-radio" name="ket_jawaban[<?php echo $no2;?>]" value="<?php echo $row->pil4;?>" oninput="this.className = ''"><?php echo $row->pil4;?>
<input type="radio" class="w3-radio" name="ket_jawaban[<?php echo $no2;?>]" value="<?php echo $row->pil5;?>" oninput="this.className = ''"> <?php echo $row->pil5;?>
```

My Javascript Validation

```
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("*");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "" || !y[i].checked) {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

How to fix this for validation radio botton?

This code can validate input type text, but not type radio...
I think my problem in this code `!y[i].checked`
please helpme to fix it

This is image my program [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LRLY.png)

Comment: What do you consider to be "invalid" for your radio button? And why do you have only one radio button? They should be used in groups.

Comment: I have 5 radio, in this one for example

Comment: So, again, what do you consider "invalid"? Are you trying to test whether the user has clicked one of the buttons in the radio group?

Comment: yes, to test whether the user has clicked one of the buttons in the radio group

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code it looks like every box that is not checked will become invalid. I would initiate valid with false and then in the for loop if there is a checked radio and its value is not empty you can make valid = true. But if you want to make all other unchecked radios invalid, add " invalid" to the name of the class in the else block.

```
function validateForm() {
    var x, y, i, valid = false; // Change valid to false
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("*");

    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
      if (y[i].value !== "" && y[i].checked) {  
        valid = true;
      } else {
        y[i].className += " invalid";
      }
    }

    if (valid) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
    }
    return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

Comment: but sir, if input type Text it's error.... not null or null return false

Comment: 'if (y[i].value !== "" || y[i].checked)' i try like this, it's always return true for Input type text or radio...